# adding custom message to github PR status area

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

Is there a way to add content to this part of the PR timeline in Github?

[image: Github PR status area]

In our deployment workflow, I can receive back an environment-specific permalink that I'd like to display on the PR, like "click here to view the environment for this PR." I have found `$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` which I can use at the end of a workflow to put content into the step status screen but I'd love to have it all here in the PR if possible.

Comment: Are you using the `environment` attribute in the workflow? It has an attribute `url` that might be helpful. Environments are shown in PRs, but not in this "checks" area. If you want to show something in this area, you need to create an app or action, but even then: when everything is green, it's collapsed.

Comment: Hadn't actually seen that before - I'll take a look and see how dynamic I can make it. Also might look to make a new comment on the PR after a successful run, listing the URL.